# Generating xml from full xpath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, xsd, xml-parsing

I got xpath like below in xpath

In xpath, character '[r]', '[k]', '[i]' means iter and I can find the start number of Iter.
and UUIDofk-thdrug also variables, also I have.

I tried extract only tag value in xml path like below
/MCCI_IN200100UV01/PORR_IN049016UV/controlActProcess/subject/investigationEvent/component/ .....

with this I would like to generate xml code including attribute

```css
/hl7:MCCI_IN200100UV01[@ITSVersion='XML_1.0'][@xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd']/hl7:PORR_IN049016UV[r]/hl7:controlActProcess[@classCode='CACT'][@moodCode='EVN']/hl7:subject[@typeCode='SUBJ'][1]/hl7:investigationEvent[@classCode='INVSTG']
[@moodCode='EVN']/hl7:component[@typeCode='COMP'][hl7:adverseEventAssessment][1]/hl7:adverseEventAssessment[@classCode='INVSTG'][@moodCode='EVN']/hl7:component[@typeCode='COMP'][hl7:causalityAssessment/hl7:code[@code='39'][@codeSystem='2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.1.19']][r]/hl7:causalityAssessment[@classCode='OBS'][@moodCode='EVN'][hl7:subject1[@typeCode='SUBJ']/hl7:adverseEffectReference[@classCode='OBS'][@moodCode='EVN']/hl7:id[@root='UUIDofi-threaction']][hl7:subject2[@typeCode='SUBJ']/hl7:productUseReference[@classCode='SBADM'][@moodCode='EVN']/hl7:id[@root='UUIDofk-thdrug']]/hl7:value[@xsi:type='ST']/text()
```

Hand written example is below.
I want to put my value into the proper path, in above example xpath, the value will be inserted like below example xml.

```html
<<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MCCI_IN200100UV01 ITSVersion="XML_1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
    <PORR_IN049016UV>
  
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
        <controlActProcess classCode="CACT" moodCode="EVN">
        
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
          <subject typeCode="SUBJ">
          
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
            <investigationEvent classCode="INVSTG" moodCode="EVN">
            
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
                <component typeCode="COMP">
                
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
                    <adverseEventAssessment classCode='INVSTG' moodCode='EVN'>
                    
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
                        <component typeCode="COMP">
                        
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
                            <causalityAssessment classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                            
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
                                <code code="39" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.1.19" codeSystemVersion="1.1" displayName="causality"/>
                                    <value xsi:type="ST">PUT MY VALUE</value>
                                    
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
                                    <subject1 typeCode="SUBJ">
                                      <adverseEffectReference classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                                          <id root="154eb889-958b-45f2-a02f-42d4d6f4657f"/>
                                      </adverseEffectReference>
                                    </subject1>
                                    
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
                                </causalityAssessment>
                                
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
                            </component>
                            
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
                        </adverseEventAssessment>
                        
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
                    </component>
                    
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
                </investigationEvent>
                
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
            </subject>
            
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
        </controlActProcess>
        
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
    </PORR_IN049016UV>
    
          """" INSERT SOMETHING MORE DEPENDS ON XPATH """"
</MCCI_IN200100UV01>
```

What is the best way to generate xml with above like xpath in python?

Comment: Sorry, but the question is unclear. I don't understand at all. Why do you need to generate XML? What should the XML look like?

Comment: @mzjn I added output and what I want to :)